# Cannot read application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I write Spring Boot application. I use file application.properties to contains configuration of database. But now I want to get properties from application.yml which contains:

```
rest:
  response: RESPONSE

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Value("${rest.response}")
    private String restResponse;

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register() {
        return restResponse;
    }
}
```

Directory resources contains application.properties and application.yml. Why I cannot import properties from .yml?

Comment: you have both application.properties and application.yml in one directory?

Comment: yes, I have these files in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'application.yml' , if the RESPONSE that is read from application.yml contains characters such as + , - etc , put the value inside single inverted commas otherwise it won't be read properly(since it is mapped to a string variable).

Answer (score 0):

check that `org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26` is in `classpath` (or `spring-boot-starter` is in dependencies)